# XPath Query across multiple XML files?

Tags: xml, xpath, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,

I am using NotePad++ Version 6.1.2 and a XML XPath Query Analyzer Plugin for NotePad++ called "xpatherizernpp" located in the link below:

http://code.google.com/p/xpatherizernpp/

How does one perform a XPath query for multiple XML files? 
From what I have Googled you need to write an expression similar to what is shown below:

`collection('file:///c:/?select=`

However, the xpatherizernpp does not like the "collection" command.

In short, I have three XML files inside this path: C:\root\xpath_test\

My goal is to lasso (query) all `<title>` elements from all three XML files. I would appreciate any help anyone can provide for the correct XPath expression I need to use to accomplish the task of performing a XPath query across multiple XML files.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

No need XPath for searching the content on multiple XML's.

Notepad++ has a feature called **"Find In Files"**, to find content on all files.

### Steps to perform:

1. Open Notepad++
2. Press **<kbd>CTRL+F</kbd>**
3. Click `"Find In Files"` Tab
4. Enter `"Find What"` text as ""
5. Enter the directory path
6. Click `"Find All"` button

Comment: Thanks for the post Siva,
What you are suggesting works great. However, I want to learn how to author Xpath expressions and therefore I need to learn how to use the "collection" command.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thnx.